# Is there a general algorithm to find a primitive element of a given finite extension (with a finite number of intermediate fields)?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I just want to know if there is an algorithm to find the primitive element of a given finite extension $F/k$ if the intermediate fields are given. I know how to approach it in particular examples picking linear combinations (the case $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}$ for instance). If it does not exists, is there, then, an algorithm for the finite separable extension case or for extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pick a random element. No, really.

Comment: If you read the proof of the primitive element theorem you'll understand why Qiaochu's comment is accurate.

Comment: In Lisl Gaal's *Classical Galois Theory* there is a description of an algorithm for computing a primitive element. I don't have the book with me now but I can try to post it when I do unless someone else answers your question.