# How can you write $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2},\omega_3]$ using a single algebraic element $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Looking at  the basis of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2},\omega_3]$ gives me no idea on how to generate it using $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4,\alpha^5\}$ for some $\alpha$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Is $\omega$ a primitive root of the unit?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that I was looking at the splitting field of $x^3-2$ and wondered how to write it using only one element.

Comment: It will be of the form $\sqrt[3]2+r\omega_3$ for some rational $r,$ but off the top of my head, I couldn't tell you what it is.

Comment: [Here's a paper](https://www.math.washington.edu/~greenber/MATH404-PrimElem.pdf) that may be helpful.  But in general, I think if you just pick some random $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\sqrt[3]{2} + r \omega_3$ will usually be a primitive element.

Comment: Oh, and here is a [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391917/is-there-a-general-algorithm-to-find-a-primitive-element-of-a-given-finite-exten) with no answers, unfortunately..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $K$ is an infinite field and $\alpha,\beta$ are separable algebraic over $K$, then there is some $u \in K$ such that the $\alpha_i + u \beta_j$ are pairwise distinct, where $\alpha_i,\beta_j$ are the conjugates of $\alpha,\beta$. This is exactly what happens in the proof of the primitive element theorem. One then proves that $\alpha + u \beta$ is a primitive element of $K(\alpha,\beta)$. Actually in many cases $u=1$ will do the job.

Let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\beta=\omega_3$. The conjugates of $\alpha$ are $\alpha \beta^i$ with $i=0,1,2$. The conjugates of $\beta$ are $\beta^j$ with $j=1,2$. One computes (with a computer algebra software for instance) that the elements $\alpha \beta^i + \beta^j$ are pairwise distinct. Hence, $\sqrt[3]{2}+\omega_3$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega_3)$.