# Finding defining polynomial of a relative number field extension

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Say I have some number field $K_1/\mathbb{Q}$ defined as:
$$K_1 \cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$$
for some irreducible (monic, if this makes things easier) polynomial $f(x)$.
Now, let $g(x)\in K_1[x]$ be an irreducible (monic) polynomial over $K_1$.  I can then define the relative field extension $K_2$ as:
$$K_2\cong K_1[x]/\langle g(x)\rangle$$

Now, $K_2/K_1/\mathbb{Q}$ is a tower of field extensions, but we can view $K_2/\mathbb{Q}$ directly as a number field. How can I go about finding the defining polynomial of $K_2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?
By this, I mean the irreducible (monic) polynomial $h(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that:
$$K_2\cong \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle h(x)\rangle$$

Comment: I am not sure if there will be a simple relation between $h$ and $f, g$. But you can find a primitive element for $K_2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ by considering sufficiently many linear combinations of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (where $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$ in $K_1$ and $\beta$ is a root of $g(x)$ in $K_2$), i.e. an element of the form $\gamma = \alpha + c\beta$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then you can compute its minimal polynomial by computing the $[K_2:\mathbb{Q}]$ powers of $\gamma$ and use linear algebra to find a linear combination over $\mathbb{Q}$ that sums to 0.

Comment: I'd be interested to know about faster and clever algorithms (which I am sure there are!)

Comment: Note for example with $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ and $g(x) = x^2 - 3$, the fields are $K_1 = \mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $K_2 = K_1(\sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, i)$. But neither $i$ nor $\sqrt{3}$ are primitive elements of $K_2/\mathbb{Q}$. One possible primitive element is $\sqrt{3} + i$, with minimal polynomial $h(x) = x^4 - 4x^2 + 16$. But another option would be $\sqrt{3} + 2i$ whose minimal polynomial is $h(x) = x^4 + 2x^2 + 49$. Thus the polynomial $h$ does not even have to be unique (note that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + 2i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, i))$.

Comment: @TobErnack For $\gamma=\alpha+c\beta$, it seems like a random $c$ works with high probability according to [here](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/6310/primitive.pdf) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391917/is-there-a-general-algorithm-to-find-a-primitive-element-of-a-given-finite-exten). This might explain why in Henri Cohen's A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory, [it is suggested that we can take $c$ for a small integer.](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=5TP6CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179#v=onepage&q&f=false)  (cont.)

Comment: (continued) Then it seems like this method reduces to efficiently checking if $\alpha$ or $\beta \in \mathbb Q(\gamma)$, since in that case the other element is also in $\mathbb Q(\gamma)$ and $\mathbb Q(\alpha,\beta)=\mathbb Q(\gamma)$. Changing $c$ if it fails. Henri Cohen's book also has a section that can solve this, called the subfield problem (same chapter)